# Displaying dynamic text on a Rect in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to display a dynamically changing `energy` score text on a moving Rect in Pygame. I'm doing:

```
class Creature(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, color=RED, agent=None, size=(30, 20)):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([size[0], size[1]])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=x
        self.rect.y=y
        ...
        self.energy = 200
    
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 36)
        self.text = self.font.render(self.energy, False, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(self.text, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))


    def update(self):
        self.energy -= 1
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 36)
        self.text = self.font.render(self.energy, False, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(self.text, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```

However, no text appears. Everything else works fine, I'm showing and updating the rectangle on screen. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't blit the text on the screen. Blit it to `self.image1` at coordinates (0, 0). The `Sprite` class will automatically draw it for you. Try that

Comment: It's not necessary to recreate `self.font` in every call to `update()`, because it's *already* created in the `__init__()`.  Just re-use the existing font (by removing the line that calls SysFont() in update()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw the text after drawing the sprites in the group. Add a function `draw_label` to the class:

```py
class Creature(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   # [...]

   def update(self):
        self.energy -= 1

   def draw_label(self):
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 36)
        self.text = self.font.render(self.energy, False, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(self.text, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```

Call the function after drawing the sprites:

```py
creatures = pygame.sprite.Group()

while True:
    # [...]

    creatures.update()

    creatures.draw(screen)
    for creature in creatures:
        creatures.draw_label()
    pygame.display.update()
```